# Can I leave my U.S. car in Mexico on an FM3 visa?

Tags: legal, automobiles, regulations, mexico

As a U.S. citizen in Mexico on an FM3 visa, can I leave my car in Mexico when I travel to other countries as long as my visa is still current, or must my car follow me when I leave the country?

If it is legal to leave my car in Mexico, how long can I leave it there?  I would guess if it is permitted, it would be limited to the expiration date on my FM3 visa.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?  You want to leave it and make sure it's not stolen?

Comment: @Karlson: Mexico has very strict laws forbidding "smuggling" cars across the border into the country. There's a bunch of paperwork in which you promise to take the car back with you and not leave or sell it in Mexico. Penalties apply if you break this agreement. This is a good question and I don't know the answer.

Comment: my understanding is that an FM3 visa is not a tourist visa, but an immigration one?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yes.  There are different subclasses of FM3 visas, which allow you to study, work, retire in Mexico.  But in general, they allow you to live there long-term... I think they are good for at least 2 years, often longer.

Comment: @Karlson: I want to know if it's legal to leave it there.  I'll be back to pick it up after traveling.

Comment: How long are you planning to leave the car in Mexico?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Perhaps that should be part of my question: How long *can* I leave it in Mexico?  Given complete freedom, perhaps a few months.

Comment: @Flimzy - so which subclass are you on, then?

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a named classification, but I'll be there, authorized to work for a foreign company.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you do it?

Comment: @MarkMayo: I have not done it... but I have a friend who has.  Although I don't know if he's doing it correctly/legally.  When I have something more solid than simple hearsay, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: where do you want to leave it at?

Comment: @LuisOscar: At a friend's house probably. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Mexican Customs website has **[this](http://www.aduanas.gob.mx/aduana_mexico/2008/descargas/folletos08/vehiculosespcartel.pdf)** document, which states aliens can *temporarily import* a car into Mexico **for as long as their immigration status lasts**. In your case, this would be until your FM3 visa expires. Quote:

> "Cuánto tiempo puede permanecer en México el vehículo  importado ... **el plazo que dure tu calidad migratoria**"

Also, the Mexican Ministry of Turism (Secretaria de Turismo, SECTUR), provides [this document](http://www.sectur.gob.mx/work/models/sectur/Resource/1299/1/images/Manual_Internacion_Turista_2012.pdf), which on page 16, section 3.2.2.1, states:

> "Para ingresar un automóvil que sea de procedencia extranjera (con
>   placas distintas a las de México), se requiere contar con un permiso
>   de Importación Temporal. Dicho permiso se obtiene en cualquier módulo
>   de BANJERCITO ubicado en las aduanas y se otorga para los extranjeros,
>   **por el plazo que dure su calidad migratoria**, incluyendo sus prórrogas y para los mexicanos, por 180 días dentro de un año, con la opción de  entradas y salidas múltiples, siempre y cuando se cumplan
>   con los siguientes requisitos..."

Which translates to:

> "To bring an alien car into the country, you need to have a Temporary
>   Import permit, which you can get at any BANJERCITO desk at the customs
>   office, and is granted to aliens, **for the term that their
>   immigration status lasts**... as long as you abide to the following
>   requisites..."